# phonegap-plugin-push error 65 upon building: GoogleCloudMessaging.h is deprecated. Can we remove this from the project? Quickfix?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap, phonegap-plugin-push

I have an iOS cordova project that we recently updated to platform iOS@5.0.0

Upon compiling the project, we encountered error 65 on phonegap-plugin-push/PlushPlugin.m
Tried doing a `pod install` on the ios folder as according to the first solution [here](https://medium.com/@zwacky/ios-android-native-build-errors-with-cordova-plugins-102bf4dd3c66) it would help resolve the problem.. however the problem still persist

Upon reading further [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/ios-migrate-fcm), it says

> On April 10, 2018, Google deprecated GCM. The GCM server and client
>   APIs were removed on May 29, 2019. Migrate GCM apps to Firebase Cloud
>   Messaging (FCM), which inherits the reliable and scalable GCM
>   infrastructure, plus many new features. See the migration guide to
>   learn more

Since I am building the app for iOS, can I just remove this plugin? Is there a quick fix that we can do to immediately resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Removed the component, as it was not necessary to build the app

`sudo cordova plugin rm phonegap-plugin-push`

was able to build the app without error.

The plugin has also been [discontinued](https://blog.phonegap.com/discontinuing-the-phonegap-push-service-540251bfc98)